# Use of Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing a Coursera python exercise and having trouble writing my code.

The question is as following:

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has the sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail.

The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.
The sample text file is in this line: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt

And the expected output should be:

cwen@iupui.edu 5

This is my code:

```
 name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
name="mbox-short.txt"
handle=open(name)
text=handle.read()
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip()
    words=line.split()
    if words==[]: continue
    if words[0]!='From':continue
    words2=words[1]
words3=words2.split()
counts=dict()
for word in words3:
     counts[word]=counts.get(word,0)+1



bigcount=None
bigword=None
for key,val in counts.items():
 if val>bigcount:
    bigword=key
    bigcount=val
print bigword,bigcount
```

My Output is:
cwen@iupui.edu 1

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: Dunno. What's going wrong?

Comment: try with `for line in text` instead of `for line in handle`

Comment: My output should be cwen@iupui.edu 5. But its coming cwen@iupui.edu 1

Comment: @dhdavvie I tried but its not working

Comment: I don't see how it produces anything but a `NameError` on `words2`, because `handle` should be empty due to having done `handle.read()` and then only defining `words2` in the `for line in handle` loop, as nothing in that loop will execute because the file object's pointer is at the end.

Comment: Try to refactor your code without words2 and words3 that are useless anyway.

Comment: @dhdavvie - `for line in text` would go character by character, which probably isn't desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need, you're not storing the words2 output in the list, and as mentioned in the comments you're recursing the file in a wrong manner too.

Hope this will help you.

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
name="mbox-short.txt"
handle=open(name)
words3 = []
for line in handle:
    line=line.rstrip()
    words=line.split()
    if words==[]: continue
    if words[0]!='From':continue
    words2=words[1]
    words3.append(words2.split()[0])
    # print words
counts=dict()
for word in words3:
     counts[word]=counts.get(word,0)+1


bigcount=None
bigword=None
for key,val in counts.items():
 if val>bigcount:
    bigword=key
    bigcount=val
print bigword,bigcount
```

Comment: There's no need to read the file, split it, and iterate over the resulting list. You can skip that and iterate over the file object itself.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks dude, I didn't know that.

Comment: can u explain the use of 'words3.append(words2.split()[0])'. Actually i am new to python...

Comment: spliting it and getting first element of that array we get after spliting it up.

Comment: use print statements wherever you think you don't get something it will print that out for you, making easy to understand.